# MacOS cannot open external links with chrome but safari

Tags: google-chrome, web-browser

I cannot open external links in Mail/Slack/Discord if I set the default browser to Chrome. I can open them with Safari though. I found the following thread explains the reason, but running every app as Admin is not realistic in my opinion.

https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/ft2xkp/cant_open_link_in_discord_with_chrome_as_browser/

Do you have any idea for solving this problem without running every app as Admin nor using Safari as the default browser?

Comment: So this is a Chrome issue then.

Comment: This does not happen on Windows/Linux. If MacOS did not interrupt opening links with Chrome, everything goes well. I want to find how to turn off/bypass this permission policy.